# I have created a triangular body with physicsbox2d andengine Extention..how to add face or sprite to the body

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I have created a triangular body with physicsbox2d andengine Extention. it looks gud ..now i am not able to add face or sprite to this triangular body ...here is code ..thankx in advance.`

```
List<Vector2> UniqueBodyVertices = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
        UniqueBodyVertices.addAll((List<Vector2>) ListUtils.toList(
        new Vector2[] {
        new Vector2(-93f,-75f),
        new Vector2(-107f,-14f),
        new Vector2(-101f,41f),
        new Vector2(-71f,74f),
        new Vector2(69f,74f),
        new Vector2(98f,41f),
        new Vector2(104f,-14f),
        new Vector2(51f,-75f),
        new Vector2(79f,9f),
        new Vector2(43f,34f),
        new Vector2(-46f,34f),
        new Vector2(-80f,9f)
        }));
        List<Vector2> UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated = new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(UniqueBodyVertices);


        float[] MeshTriangles =
                new float[UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size() * 3];
                for(int i = 0; i < UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size(); i++) {
                MeshTriangles[i*3] = UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.get(i).x;
                MeshTriangles[i*3+1] = UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.get(i).y;
                UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.get(i).
                mul(1/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
                }
                Mesh UniqueBodyMesh = new Mesh(400f, 260f, MeshTriangles,
                UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size(), DrawMode.TRIANGLES,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                UniqueBodyMesh.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f);
                scene.attachChild(UniqueBodyMesh);

                FixtureDef uniqueBodyFixtureDef =
                        PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(20f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

                        Body uniqueBody = PhysicsFactory.createTrianglulatedBody(
                        mphysicworld, UniqueBodyMesh ,UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated,
                        BodyType.DynamicBody, uniqueBodyFixtureDef);
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to connect your uniquebody with UniqueBodyMesh (which is entity like sprite). Judging from your code you should be able to see your sprite covering your body. But it is not connected so after contact it will not move with your body. You need additionally:

```
mphysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(UniqueBodyMesh, uniqueBody, true, true));
```

Comment: ur right #lukasz ..but what really i was seraching for was this ..[http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/understanding-textures-texturesources-textureregions-t546.html]

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the body to the desired sprite by using a physics connector, and then registering that physics connector to the physics world object. For example:

```
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true));
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/creating-bodies.html) for more info (especially under "Creating Moving Body" part).